# Creating a table in gist

Tags: markdown

I am a noob in programming and would like to know how to stack multiple lines of text in one cell of the table. This is what I am talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<br/>` tag just after the text you want to break the line and it will get the job done.

Update:

The table would look like this

```html
|  First   | Second                       |
| -------- | ---------------------------- |
|  Heading |  # H1<br/> ## H2</br> ### H3 |
```